# Google Authentication - Login

Tags: php, google-authentication

I have built a website and intend users to login with their google account, they will be able to make comments using their google email address on my site.

I have work my way through googles documentation and am now confused.

https://developers.google.com/accounts/

I have managed to get the user to authorise the use of their details and google returns the access token etc in the query string:

access_token

token_type=Bearer

expires_in=3600

My problem is how to get the users email address using the access token.  I realise this means making a request to google.  But how?

I simply would like help with hopefully a couple of lines of code to go to google and get the users email using my php page.  Just the simplest php example if anyone has one?

I have been searching for hours and am now at a loss.

Thanks

Comment: Did you implement this from scratch or are you using an openId library? If from scratch, then I'd recommend you go get one of the well developed and supported libs available - the Janrain one is well written, and is the basis for several tutorials.

Comment: I was following this guide: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login.  But was a little unsure on the java at the bottom of the page.  I thought it may have been simpler to do a quick request to google and get the user details as I would like the email address to use in my DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my expereince google client doesn't give the user email but you can get it using an oath2 response.

once you have the access token you can do this. hope this helps

require_once 'path_to_your_google_library/Google_Client.php';

require_once 'path_to_your_google_library/contrib/Google_Oauth2Service.php';

$google_instance = new Google_Client();

$oath2 = new Google_Oauth2Service($google_instance);

$oauth_response = $oauth2->userinfo->get();

$email_of_user = $oauth_response['email'];